# angular ng-repeat array show only one element

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have an array like this

```
 $scope.mentors = [ {"name":"Jonathan", "status":0},
                    {"name": "Nathan","status":1},
                    {"name": "Chris","status":1},
                    {"name": "Brian","status":0}];
```

here my view code

```
<div ng-repeat="m in mentors">
   <div ng-if="m.status == '1'">
   <div>
     {{m.name}}
   </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

and my result is :
Nathan and Chris

what can I do to just make it show Nathan  or Chris 
it must only **show one result only**

p/s: already try ng-show="$last" it did not work since Brian status is '0'

Comment: Why do you need only one result ? Do you need to show Nathan or Chris ?

Comment: @Weedoze it can Nathan or Chris but it must only show one. if possible i want Nathan to show first until Nathan status is 0, then it will show Chris.. i hope it not too confusing

Comment: I guess you could use `limitTo` in your `ng-repeat`

Comment: @Und3rTow try it already it did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the array on statuses and then just take the first by checking against $index

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.mentors = [ {"name":"Jonathan", "status":0},
                    {"name": "Nathan","status":1},
                    {"name": "Chris","status":1},
                    {"name": "Brian","status":0}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="m in mentors | filter : {status: 1}">
   <div ng-if="$index == 0">
     <div>
       {{m.name}}
     </div>

   </div>
   </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the same code as provided. This does not provide the expected output

Comment: sorry no i only want nathan to show not chris as well.. and if nathan status turn '0' only then it will show chris

Comment: yes thank you !!... this is exactly like i wanted !! thank @MarcusHöglund

Answer (score 2):

You could use the limitTo and  filter

```
<div ng-repeat="m in mentors | filter: { status : '1'}| limitTo : 1">
  <div>
   {{m.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you i din't know that filter and limitTo can be used like this

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use `ng-repeat` if you only need to display 1 item.

You should handle this in your controller. Create a new variable that will hold the mentor that you want to show.

To find Nathan, you can use `Array#find()`. It will return the first item that matches the condition `status === 1`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.mentors = [{
      "name": "Jonathan",
      "status": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "Nathan",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris",
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Brian",
      "status": 0
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.mentor = $scope.mentors.find(m => m.status === 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>{{mentor.name}}</h1>
</div>
```